# Spline basis explicitly including a linear term; basis functions generated by the default call to "s()" function of mgcv package

Tags: generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv, smoothing, basis-function

I'm curious about the basis functions generated by the call to "s()" function with default parameter values, but even more specifically I'm curious about a smoother for a single variable *varname* that would explicitly have a linear term for that variable (a term perfectly correlated with that single variable on the entire real line). I'd like that linear term for the purposes of leveraging certain penalized regression techniques later on that would allow to determine whether the variable is best modeled linearly (via that one linear term) or non-linearly (via the entire spline).

I know that, by default, *s()* delivers a thin plate spline. Presume I use *k=4* for the dimension of the spline, then it gives me 3 spline terms (the "s(varname).1", "s(varname).2", "s(varname).3"). I don't fully understand how these are calculated, but I picked up on the fact that the **last term** (in this case, "s(varname).3") is perfectly correlated with the original variable *varname*. This tendency repeats itself for different k value (e.g. for k=6 it would be "s(varname).5" that's perfectly correlated with *varname*) and for other variables.

Would sincerely appreciate if someone could:

1. Confirm that the last term of a thin plate spline generated by default "*s()*" function call for a single numeric variable will always be perfectly correlated with that variable
2. Shed more light on precisely how these basis functions are calculated in case of a default "*s()*" function call for a single numeric variable
3. Provide examples of other, non-default, spline types - among those provided by *s()* function - that explicitly include a linear term for the original variable (if any)?

Comment: To close voters: please stop voting to close questions like this for programming reasons. The question is about the statistical inference involved in GAMs, not programming-related queries like debugging code.

Comment: You can at the outset cut short your queries. At present it needs to focus on a single or two question.

Comment: This being closed is a bit unfortunate - I could answer all of this pretty simply. part 3 is asking a bit much

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand - the first two of the three questions, at least, are absolutely programming questions.  They are asking about the return value from a particular function in a particular package in a particular language and how the underlying code does the calculations involved, respectively.

Comment: It is almost impossible to talk about GAMs without at least talking about R or it's associated packages like `mgcv`, `gratia`, etc. Consequently, almost every statistical question involving GAMs is going to be related to its functions. The first question asks whether or not a given function will cause perfect correlations, which general programmers won't normally know. The second question asks how basis functions are calculated, which requires statistical expertise to answer. The third question asks about different spline types, which has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: We can respectfully disagree on this point, but I don't see this as a programming question. This is asking for what is going on "under the hood."

Comment: @jbowman I respectfully disagree; the first question relates to Simon Woods low rank thin plate spline idea. In the full thin plate spline basis you wouldn't see this IIRC as none of the basis functions is a linear function. While the main implementation of this is in Simon's mgcv package, there is no restriction to it being in R. To answer Q1 and Q2 one would need to talk about the eigendecomposition of the full rank tps basis and why this is done, which isn't programming either. I guess it depends on how you interpret "calculated", but I don't see the OP as asking for R/programming code.

Comment: My apologies for all the controversy, but even though I am indeed primarily interested in the output obtained from a programming function, my question(s) is vastly about the theory and methodology behind those calculations. E.g. how are the basis functions calculated for a thin plate spline, what kind of splines have a pure linear term as one of their basis functions, is it reasonable to see a basis function perfectly correlated with the original variable, etc. Moreover, as already mentioned by others, s() function/mgcv package are cornerstones when talking about GAMs... but oh well

Comment: @GavinSimpson Seems like the question reopened, and you were saying that you could answer most of it - could you please post a full answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Q1

Yes, with the default univariate smooth `s(x)` there will always be one basis function that is a linear function and hence perfectly correlated with `x`. That this is the last function is, I think, implementational; nothing changes if you put this linear basis function first or anywhere in the set of basis functions.

Note, however, that reducing the default size of the penalty null space will remove this linear basis function: with `s(x, m = c(2, 0))`, we are requesting a low-rank thin plate regression spline (TPRS) basis with 2nd order derivative penalty and zero penalty null space. As the linear function is in the penalty null space (it is not affected by the wiggliness penalty as it has second derivative of 0), it will be removed from the basis.

If we have a bivariate low rank TPRS, then there will be a linear plane that is perfectly correlated with $x_1$ and another that is linearly correlated with $x_2$ for low rank TPRS $f(x_1,x_2)$.

#### Q2

I'm not going to repeat Wood (2003) — if you want the math behind thin plate splines, read that paper or §5.5 of (the second edition of) Simon's book (2017) for the detail.

The raw basis functions for the univariate thin plate spline are given by

$$
\eta_{md}(r) = \frac{\Gamma(d/2 - m)}{2^{2m}\pi^{d/2}(m-1)!} r^{2m-d}
$$

for $d$ odd and here $d = 1$ as we are speaking about a univariate spline. $m$ is the order of the penalty, so be default $m = 2$. $r = \| \mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j \|$, i.e. the Euclidean distance between the data $\mathbf{x}_i$ and the control points or knots $\mathbf{x}_j$, the latter being the unique values of $\mathbf{x}_i$.

These functions look like this

```r
# definition from Wood 2017 and Wood 2003 JRSSB
# this is for a 1 dimensional smooth (d) with 2nd order derivative penalty (m)
eta <- function(x, x0) {
    d <- 1
    m <- 2
    r <- sqrt((x - x0)^2)
    top <- gamma((d/2) - m)
    bot <- (2^(2*m) * pi^(d/2)) * factorial(m-1)
    (top / bot) * r^((2*m) - d)
}

tprs <- function(x, knots = NULL, null_space = TRUE) {
    require("tidyr")
    # want a basis function per unique x if no control points provided
    if (is.null(knots)) {
        knots <- sort(unique(x))
    }
    bf <- outer(x, knots, FUN = eta)
    if (null_space) {
        bf <- cbind(rep(1, length(x)), x, bf)
    }
    
    # convert to a tibble for easy plotting in ggplot
    n_knots <- length(knots)
    n_bf <- ifelse(null_space, n_knots + 2, n_knots)
    colnames(bf) <- paste0("bf", seq_len(n_bf))
    bf <- bf |>
        tidyr::as_tibble() |>
        tibble::add_column(x, .before = 1L) |>
        tidyr::pivot_longer(!all_of("x"), names_to = "bf", names_prefix = "bf") |>
        dplyr::mutate(bf = factor(bf, levels = seq_len(n_bf)))
    bf
}


set.seed(1)
x_ref <- seq(0, 1, length = 100)
x <- runif(20)
knots <- sort(unique(x))

bfuns <- tprs(x_ref, knots = x)

library("ggplot2")

bfuns |>
    ggplot(aes(y = value, x = x, group = bf, colour = bf)) +
    geom_line() +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    facet_wrap(~ bf, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Basis functions 1 and 2 are the functions in the penalty null space for this basis (they have 0 second derivative).

For practical usage, the basis needs to have identifiability constraints applied to it; typically this is a sum-to-zero constraint. As a result the knot-based (1 basis function per $\mathbf{x}_j$) thin plate spline basis looks like this:

```r
library("gratia")

x_red <- seq(0, 1, length = 50)
x <- runif(7)
knots <- sort(unique(x))

bfs <- basis(s(x, k = 7), data = data.frame(x = x), knots = list(x = knots), 
             at = data.frame(x = x.ref), constraints = FALSE)
draw(bfs) & facet_wrap(~bf)
```

[image]

Here shown for 7 data, hence 7 basis functions. This is achieved in mgcv by passing in the `knots` argument and having it be the same length as `k`. If you want to do this with large `n` and hence `k` you will likely need to read `?tprs` and note the setting `max.knots`.

By default however, mgcv doesn't use this knot-based tprs basis. Instead it uses the low-rank approach of Wood (2004), but applies and eigendecomposition to the full basis, and retains the eigenvectors associated $k$-largest eigenvalues as a new basis. The point of this is that we can retain much of the original, rich basis in the low-rank one, thus providing a close approximation to the ideal spline basis, without needing $n$ basis functions (number of unique data points), i.e. covariates. This low-rank solution requires a computationally costly eigendecomposition, but mgcv uses an algorithm such that it only ever needs to find the eigenvectors for the $k$-largest eigenvalues, not the full set of eigenvectors. Even so, for large $n$ this is still computationally costly and `?tprs` suggests what to do in such cases.

These eigendecomposition-based basis functions, for the same 7 data as above, look like this

```r
bfs_eig <- basis(s(x, k = 7), data = data.frame(x = x_ref), constraints = FALSE)
draw(bfs_eig) & facet_wrap(~bf)
```

[image]

Note that in these plots I'm showing the basis with the constant function included. In a typical model, the constant function is removed because it is confounded with the intercept.

#### Q3

The only other basis in mgcv that has this property is the Duchon spline (`bs = "ds"`). This is not surprising as the thin plate spline is a special case of the more general class of Duchon splines.

This is not to say that other bases do not include the linear function in their span; they do, but this is achieved through a specific weighting of the individual basis functions, and as such there isn't a basis function that is linear in the other bases in mgcv.

#### References

Wood, S.N., 2003. Thin plate regression splines. J. R. Stat. Soc. Series B Stat. Methodol. 65, 95–114. https://doi.org/10.1111/1467-9868.00374
§

Wood, S.N., 2017. Generalized Additive Models: An Introduction with R, Second Edition. CRC Press.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is phenomenally thorough. And I understand the part about specific weighting of basis functions yielding the original variable's linear term. The thing is, I was specifically looking for a basis that explicitly included a linear term so that the model could be later seamlessly tested for "linear vs non-linear relationship" by testing if all the other terms, besides the linear one, are significant. Otherwise, I'm sort of stuck with just testing the whole spline, which doesn't automatically tell me about the linear vs non-linear distinction (need to check effect displays)

Comment: @UsDAnDreS A test can be performed, fit `gam(y ~ x + s(x, m = c(2, 0)), data = foo, method = "REML", ...)` and then look at that model's `summary()`. The test for the smooth is exactly of no effect of the wiiggly parts of the basis.